# SSRS Format to display as percent

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, report, ssrs-2008-r2

I've gone through quite a few examples on here and I apologize if I'm asking a repeat question, as far as I can tell, I am not.

I have an SSRS report made that shows gross sales for certain aspects of our sales departments.  They are broken down, in row, by "cost, gross profit, gross profit %, order count, total sales."  The columns are the aspects of our sales.  Web sales, phone sales, etc....

In the tablix I can format a text box to display the results as numbers, but as you can see, I have also Percentage and Count in there.  I don't know how to format those within the context of the original text box format.  So I know I have everything that shows under there as a number already, but how do I handle getting the percentage to show as a percentage and the count to show as a count?

For example, all the percentages currently show as, "$0.35" and various other numbers that follow that form.  The count's currently appear as currency too.

I've used an example I found on here, "=Iif ( Me.Value = Floor ( Me.Value ) , "0%" , "0.00%" )," but all that did was make everything that showed up in that column, "0.00%"  I am fairly new to SSRS and have been cramming consistently for the past two weeks, but I just cannot find help on this.  Thank you in advance for anything you can offer.

Update: `=IIF(Fields!LVS_Web.Value=0.00, "0%", format(Fields!LVS_Web.Value, "P"))`

That worked... to a degree, but now everything is a percent.... thinking ELSE here but I don't know how ELSE goes in, I've not once seen the word ELSE.

Update 2: The thing that I've noticed is that in the statement, where it says, "=0.00, "0%"," that doesn't even really apply.  I've just put that there because I'm new to this and I just needed an argument involved.  I took the 0% and changed it to N under the condition that the number was < .99, hopeing I would just catch all of the decimals that fell below the value of 1.  Like, "$.23", which later became 23.45%, so I COULD do that, but what I don't udnerstand is it made everything else, "N," instead of a number.  Why is that?  It doesn't make everything else, "P?"

I'm losing my damned mind.

There is also the fact that this is information being pulled from a stored procedure, I don't really know too much about those quite yet, I get assigned simple tasks ever so often as a stepping stool for learning.  I don't really know what the query was, but I couldn't edit it if I wanted to.  This can be done with expression formatting but my expression is too broad, but I get mixed results using Greater or Less than, and it's probably not the wisest thing to use since these numbers are not set in stone.  My day is almost done, I've made very very little progress, but I had a good lunch.  So success.

So I provided my own answer for this problem, and it works. Thanks me.  Thanks to all the tried to help me and did help as well.  I appreciate the effort strangers will put out for each other.

I've had a new problem develop, I need to display a time relative to the data being pulled.  I can put NOW in there and get today's date, but if someone is pulling information from FEB, they may be a little off-put by the current date.  I'll probably get this figured out soon, but if anyone can help in the meantime, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Is this an Excel question? or related to some specific programming language?

Comment: this is for the SSRS reporting service in Visual Studio 2008 R2.

Comment: You should probably tag the question as SSRS or something more specific, so that the right audience sees it.

Comment: Oh lord, I thought I did that.  Sorry, a bit flustered because I know the answer is probably going to embarrass me and I've been trying to figure this out for two days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=iif(Fields!Metric.Value = "Gross Profit %",
 Format(Fields!LVS_Web.Value,"P"),
 iif(Fields!Metric.Value = "Order Count",
 Format(Fields!LVS_Web.Value,"G4"),
  Format(Fields!LVS_Web.Value,"C")))
```

This is what saved me and did what I wanted.  There is another error, but it's my bosses fault, so now I get to laugh at him.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 24):

A standard principle is to separate data from display, so use the `Value` property to store the data in its native data type and use the `Format` property to display it how you want. So rather than use an expression formatting the `Value` property such as `=Format(Fields.SomeField.Value, "0.00%")` leave the `Value` as `=Fields!SomeField.Value` and set the `Format` property to `P2`.

This is especially important when exporting your report to Excel because if you have the right data type for your data it will export to Excel as the right data type. If you use the `Format` function it will export as text, making sorting and formula not work properly.

The easiest thing to do to control the formatting is use the [standard numeric formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx). Click on the cell or range of cells that you want to have a certain format and set the `Format` property. They are a format specifier letter followed by an optional digit for precision (number of decimal places). Some useful ones are:

`C`  Currency with 2 decimal places (by default)

`N4` Number with 4 decimal places

`P0` Percentage with no decimal places

Click on the link above for the full list. Format the number cells as numbers and the percents as percents - you don't need to try to make one format string fit every cell.

These standard numeric formats also respect regional settings. You should set your report's `Language` property to `=User!Language` to use the user's regional settings rather than the report server's.

Comment: This also helped, and I marked your answer as an answer, because your, "Pep talk," here helped me arrive to where I found the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

If the number is already * 100 eg. 9.5 should be shown as 9.5% then use the format:

```
0.00\%
```

9.5 -> 9.5%

0.34 -> 0.34%

This way you can use the standard number formatting and just add the % to the end. The \ escapes the %, preventing the *100 in formatting (which would make 9.5 show 950%.).

Comment: It works in SSRS but the format is not retained when it is exported to excel. It shows the numbers as 0.00\%

Answer (score 0):

Source:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630415(v=sql.100).aspx

This is simple to use,

Percent of (the sum of line item totals for the current scope)/(the sum of line item totals for the dataset).
This value is formatted using FormatPercent specifying one decimal place.

```
="Percentage contributing to all sales: " & FormatPercent(Sum(Field!LineTotal.Value)/Sum(Field!LineTotal.Value,"Sales"),1)
```