# Round or change format for report for one column only

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I created a report that works great.

Does anybody know how to format this properly without changing the rest of the columns? See red box. The answer should be **0.01**.

I changed the format to decimal but it changes all the columns and I need the other columns to be whole numbers and the Amount OB column to be able to have decimals.

[image: Data]

Comment: Did you check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26892564/ssrs-format-to-display-as-percent?rq=1) if it resolves your concern?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this numerous ways with an RDL. One way is to set the text box properties, on the Number tab. Or you could do this in the expression of the value like so:

```
=FormatNumber(Fields!Weight.Value,2)
```

[image]

If you need to round the number you can also do that in the expression like so:

```
=Round(Fields!Weight.Value,2)
```

Comment: Like I mentioned above this changes every column. I only need the first column changed.

Comment: Changing a single text box property on a single cell does not change an entire column or row. You can however Round to two digits every time for that cell as well without affecting anything else.

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours figuring this out. I got the solution. I added the following expression in the total box for the Amount OB column.

```
=iif(Fields!MeasureDesc.Value= "Amount OB",
Format(SUM(Fields!MeasureCount.Value),"N2"), SUM(Fields!MeasureCount.Value))
```

This reads if the column equals Amount OB then use two decimal places else just sum the MeasureCount. MeasureCount are the cells that are under Amount OB.